# Send Array from JS to php file then insert it in wp database through a plugin

Tags: plugins, php, ajax, javascript

This's my code it's success but when but I can't the return data from ajax **in the same page.**
the mechanism is the user click the dropbox button and when he selects it returns `dropbox_links` and then insert `dropbox_links` in database using `add_post_meta`

**The Insert should be on the spot becuase the dropbox button click is the only trigger**

```
 $.ajax({
    
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    req: JSON.stringify(dropbox_links)
                },
    
                cache: false,
                success: function(responseData) {
                    // consider using console.log for these kind of things.
                    console.log("Data recived: " + responseData);
                    console.log(dropbox_links);
    
                },
                error: function(msg) {
                    console.log("not sure what to ask for here to check issue" + msg);
                }
            });
```

This's the php code but I don't catch or print any data so **should I re-run the whole php script to see if it returns any data?**

```
function printdata()
{
    $data    = $_POST["req"];
    $data    = json_decode($data, true);
    print_r($data);
}

if (isset($POST["req"])) {

    printdata();
} else {;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `json_encode` to return data. Also use `$_POST` instead of `$POST`.

Please try the following code for the PHP part.

```
function printdata() {
    $data = $_POST["req"];
    echo json_encode($data);
}

if (isset($_POST["req"])) {
    printdata();
} else {
    echo 'No Data';
}
```